# find a general solution for the following PDE: $u_{yx}-u_x + u_y-u=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**the question:**
$$u_{yx}-u_x + u_y-u=0$$
**my thoughts:**
I know that it's a 2nd order linear PDE so I've ruled out characteristic curves, and several ODE tricks. I also noticed that I can use $v = u_x$ and then the equation becomes:
$v_y - v + u_y - u =0$ which I've tried seperating into a system of equations a-la superposition but I'm not sure if I'm right or how to procceed. Any help would be appreciated greatly!
also unrelated but do you have a site where I can check my PDE's? haven't found one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that you equation can be written as
$$
v_x=-v
$$
where $v(x,y)=u_y-u$. Solving for $v$ (with $y$ as a parameter):
$$
v(x,y)=C(y)e^{-x}.
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary function. So we have
$$
u_y-u=C(y)e^{-x}.
$$
which is a linear equation for $u$ with $x$ as a parameter. Solving you obtain
$$
e^{-y}u=e^{-x}\int C(y)e^{-y}
$$
or
$$
u(x,y)=e^{y-x}\int C(y)e^{-y}\,dy.
$$